# Question about $f :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}$ (TIFR GS $2010$)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Question is :
 [image]

I am not sure how to check for differentiability,

only thing i know is how to see for differentiability of $f(x)=|x|$

$\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0} \frac{|x|}{x}$

But then, when $x$ approach $0$ from positive line we have $\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{|x|}{x}=1$ and  when $x$ approach $0$ from negativeline we have $\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{|x|}{x}=-1$

So, limit does not exists so the function $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $0$

But, I am not getting any idea how to proceed in case of $f(x)=|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}$

$lim_ {x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0} \frac{|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}}{x}$ I was thinking to write this as

$$\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0} \frac{|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}}{x}=\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0} \frac{|x|^{2-\frac{1}{2}}}{x}=\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0} \frac{|x|^2 .|x|^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{x}=\lim_ {x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$

as $x$ is in square rot in denominator i am unable to see what are its left and right limits for $x=0$

Please help me to proceed further..

Thank you

Comment: Answer number $c$ is correct. What is your conclusion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to denote $|x|^{3/2} = x\cdot\sigma(x)\sqrt{|x|}$, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sign of $x$. Then
$$\left|\frac{|x|^{3/2}}{x}-0\right|=\sqrt{|x|}\to 0.$$

Comment: I am sorry, I did not get your idea clearly... could you please explain a bit more.. Thank you :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik which part, exactly? The part where we define $\sigma$ (which could be denoted $\sigma(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\geq 0\\ -1 & x<0\end{cases}$), or after that?

Comment: No no, I was not seeing the $|x|$ part and was afraid of considering negative and positive direction.. now it is clear to me.. Thank you...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$$
\totald{\pars{\verts{x}^{3/2}}}{x} = {3 \over 2}\,\verts{x}^{1/2}\sgn\pars{x}
$$

Comment: I am sorry, I did not get your idea clearly... could you please explain a bit more.. Thank you :)